# How to add sub states in enum of states of player-LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

In my game,player have two main states;STATIC and MOVING.

I want to add two more states as sub states of STATIC state,like UP and DOWN.

```
public enum PlayerState {

    STATIC,MOVING;

    public boolean isMoving() {
        return this == MOVING;
    }
    public boolean isStatic() {
        return this == STATIC;

    }
```

}

How can I add this sub states in the enumeration and access it?

Now I am accessing it in player class as

```
private NestState state = NestState.STATIC;

 public void moving() {
    state = NestState.MOVING;

}

public void staticState() {
    state = NestState.STATIC;

}

public boolean isStatic() {

    return state.isStatic();
}

public boolean isMoving() {

    return state.isMoving();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 2 simple solutions that would allow you to have states and sub states. The first would be to expand the states you have at the moment.

```
public enum PlayerState {

    STATIC_STILL, STATIC_UP, STATIC_DOWN, MOVING_LEFT, MOVING_RIGHT;

    public boolean isMoving() {
         if(this == MOVING_LEFT || 
               this == MOVING_LEFT){
           return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
    public boolean isStatic() {
        if(this == STATIC_STILL || 
               this == STATIC_UP || 
               this = STATIC_DOWN){
           return true;
         }
         return false;
    }

}
```

The second option would be to create a second set of states separate from this

```
public enum PlayerSubState {
    UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT;
}
```

And your player would have both a PlayerState and a PlayerSubState.